# Regexp_replace adding extra characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using the following query in Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 / Toad for Oracle 11.6.1.6:

```
select  regexp_replace('000010PARA197427'
                      ,'([0-9]*)([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)'
                      ,'\3-\2-\1') from dual
```

Rather than getting what I expected, `197427-PARA-000010`.
I get `197427-PARA-000010--` as a result.

If I change the query to:

```
select  regexp_replace('000010PARA197427'
                      ,'([0-9]*)([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)'
                      ,'\3-c\2-c\1') from dual
```

I then get `197427-cPARA-c000010-c-c` for the result.

it's like all the literals are getting appended to the end of the result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure why this is happening, but since you only have `*` quantifiers and no anchoring, maybe you're getting an empty match (or something like that).

Anchoring the pattern (`/^...$/`) seems to work. Using `+` rather than `*` for any of the quantifier also works for this sample.

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('000010PARA197427'
                          ,'([0-9]+)([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)'
                          ,'\3-\2-\1') foo from dual ;

FOO
------------------
197427-PARA-000010

SQL> select regexp_replace('000010PARA197427'
                          ,'^([0-9]*)([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)$'
                          ,'\3-\2-\1') foo from dual ;

FOO
------------------
197427-PARA-000010
```